# I am trying to overlap a pre tag on top of a textarea, but it's just floating in the middle of its container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have spent some time trying to overlap a pre tag on top of a textarea, I am trying to build a text editor of some sort. However, somehow the pre tag is not being rendered at the top left of its container, it is being rendered in the middle. No margin or padding is pulling it down, so I am out of ideas. There is another strange thing going on, the textarea has position: absolute, but its container is still stretching itself to the textarea's height.

Out of frustration I have copied the exact code from this library: http://satya164.xyz/react-simple-code-editor/. But it still, does not work, even though it is the exact same code.

**My Current Code:**

```js
const codeEditor = document.getElementById("code-editor__textarea");
const codeRenderer = document.getElementById("code-editor__pre");

codeEditor.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  codeRenderer.innerHTML = codeEditor.value;
});
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
}

.code-editor {
  margin: 1.67em 0;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.code-editor__container {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: keep-all;
}

#code-editor__textarea,
#code-editor__pre {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant-ligatures: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
  tab-size: inherit;
  text-indent: inherit;
  text-rendering: inherit;
  text-transform: inherit;
  white-space: inherit;
  word-break: inherit;
}

#code-editor__textarea {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  outline: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  resize: none;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#code-editor__pre {
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Code Editor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="code-editor">
    <div class="code-editor__container">
      <textarea id="code-editor__textarea" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
      <pre id="code-editor__pre" aria-hidden="true"><br></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `white-space: pre-wrap;` on the container causes this. You have taken the textarea out of the flow using absolute positioning - but the line breaks before and after it are still there, and because you forced the container to honor them, they push the pre element down accordingly.

Comment: @04FS Can I give you a kiss? Just tell me where you want it. It seems that if I put everything in a single line, it works. Thank you so much! Do you mind writing an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `white-space: pre-wrap;` on the container causes this.

You have taken the textarea out of the flow using absolute positioning - but the line breaks before and after it are still there, and because you forced the container to honor them, they push the pre element down accordingly.

(Removing it will make your textarea have a smaller height in turn as well though, because that is set to 100% height of the container. But I guess that would be a desired effect in your case?)

Answer (score 0):

Just add following fields to your #code-editor__pre id

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
```

```js
const codeEditor = document.getElementById("code-editor__textarea");
const codeRenderer = document.getElementById("code-editor__pre");

codeEditor.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  codeRenderer.innerHTML = codeEditor.value;
});
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
}

.code-editor {
  margin: 1.67em 0;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.code-editor__container {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: keep-all;
}

#code-editor__textarea,
#code-editor__pre {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant-ligatures: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
  tab-size: inherit;
  text-indent: inherit;
  text-rendering: inherit;
  text-transform: inherit;
  white-space: inherit;
  word-break: inherit;
}

#code-editor__textarea {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  outline: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  resize: none;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#code-editor__pre {
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Code Editor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="code-editor">
    <div class="code-editor__container">
      <textarea id="code-editor__textarea" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
      <pre id="code-editor__pre" aria-hidden="true"><br></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast reply unfortunate this does not do the trick. If you paste a ~10 lines of CSS code snippet, you will see that the text does not overlap. I have tried this before, with no success. I find it really strange that the exact same code I linked behaves differently when I use it.